# Plesk 11 forcing redirect to non-www

Tags: hosting, virtualhost, plesk

I have ordered the new dedicated server with Plesk 11 on it. Moved my websites from old server to the new one but had some issue on opening websites.

Using .htaccess, I force the client to use the website with www. Plesk is doing contrary by default: www to non-www. A redirect loop as result ...

My question: how can I disable adding Plesk these rows by default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found out what to do in that case:

1. Go to subscriptions
2. Click the domain you would like to manage
3. Go to websites & domains
4. At the bottom of the page, find your domain (you will see "Hosting Settings" link next to it)
5. Click on "Hosting Settings"
6. Select "None" in the "Preferred domain"-dropdown
7. Save the settings by clicking "OK"

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: **anonymous**: It's worth noting that Plesk 11.5 contains a bug that prevents the 'Preferred Domain' from saving - this was specifically noticed in version 11.5.29 (but could have been apparent in earlier packages). Upgrading to 11.5.30 fixed this bug for me and the 'Preferred Domain' then saved and subsequently, the answer above started fixing this problem.

Comment: @AllenGingrich can you provide more info? I can may be help you out!

Comment: yes i have this bug too, so this standard procedure does not help

Comment: Hello, @AndVla could you please support me at creating documentation for Plesk http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/plesk/commit

Comment: Yeap, that's general config on domain level.

Comment: The correct solution is actually to change the preferered domain to the non www version so you don't need to add your lines in the .htaccess

Comment: Do you know that how can I use free ssl in plesk panel. I try to use Let's Encrypt that plesk recommends but it says "No domains have passed validation". How can I make my domain to pass validation?