# Wordpress redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on Chrome, Firefox works sometimes

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, google-chrome, redirect-loop

I am having a really difficult time trying to resolve a very mysterious issue, and I hope somebody can help.  I am using Wordpress.  I developed my own theme for Wordpress. I have used that theme for several sites in different hosting with no issue.  It was working fine on this server I am having the issue with, but for a time now it is getting more common.  I am getting a redirect loop error on Chrome ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, but it seems to be working fine on Firefox.  And sometimes it works fine on Chrome, but not on Firefox.  I did the delete cookies and temp files and cache from my browser, and it worked for a moment, after a refresh on Chrome, the issue started again.  Right now it is working on Firefox, but not on Chrome.  So this is what I have tried:

1. Check .htaccess file.  I deleted it and re-saved Permanent link settings to recreate .htaccess file.  Did not work.
2. Modified the site_url and home values in the database from domain.com to www.domain.com and http://www.domain.com and http://domain.com and did not work.
3. Disabled all plugins, even moved all them to a different folder.  Did not work.
4. Since I am using my custom theme, I disabled my theme and enabled the Wordpress default theme, and did not work.
5. Checked permission for a couple of folders.  They were all fine.
6. Checked with the Chrome Inspector, and I see a lot of 302 Moved Temporarily.

Now, I am out of ideas, and I cannot find any scenario that matches mine.  I am not sure if it is related to cache or cookies, or permissions on certain folder, or I don't know.  I believe it is something related to cookies and permission, but I cannot find any help on how this works on Wordpress and I am not even sure it is the issue.

The other thing, is this is a Linux Server with Apache.  So I dont know if it may be a Apache configuration issue or something with the server CPANEL or something.  I only have access via FTP to the root folder of my Wordpress installation, access to the database via PHPMYADMIN and access to the Wordpress administrator.  I need to make sure there is nothing else that can cause this issue in Wordpress and a way to prove if the issue is related to the Apache configuration or server related.  I am very frustrated right now, since I am out of ideas and did my best to fix this.  I really do appreciate if someone has an idea of what else can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this same problem recently and what was causing it in my case was a new 'feature' in an updated version of Plesk control panel. Plesk now automatically does a 301 redirect to the preferred domain. Now if the preferred domain in Plesk and WordPress are different or you have conflicting redirection set in your .htaccess file this could result in a redirect loop. The solution is to either change the preferred domain in Plesk or disable the redirect altogether. You mentioned that you are using Cpanel - I'm not sure if Cpanel has this wonderful 'feature' but it's another possible cause to eliminate.

Comment: I understand.. the issue is that I don't have access to the CPanel, and the admin says there is no issue with the CPanel or the server.

Comment: Can you specify a little bit that about "disable the redirect altogether" do you mean in Wordpress by editing the .htaccess? If so, what rules should I use? and in CPanel, by disabling any option related to preferred domain redirection?

Comment: By "disable the redirect altogether" I meant in CPanel, if that is where the conflicting redirect is. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783082/plesk-11-forcing-redirect-to-non-www refers to the issue in Plesk. Not sure if there is equivalent issue in Cpanel of auto generating redirects but there is a way of setting up redirects in Cpanel so check if there are any redirects set up there.

Comment: In any case the common cause for the issue you are having is conflicting redirects. Those conflicting redirects could be in Cpanel, .htaccess or WP itself. Also your browser could be caching a redirect so try clearing cache, using different browser, different computer, etc. to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Thanks, Aidan.  At the end, we moved hosting and problem solved.  The main issue was that the hosting was not maintained by us, so after moving, everthing got fixed.